# Java serialization disabled for EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I am trying out `EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit` using [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence-testing.html#)
as a guidance. I used following configuration `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.config)` which uses DisableJavaSerializer due to `akka.actor.allow-java-serialization = off` which requires me to override the config in order to test without having to specify serializer. Currently I am having to do below in order to use JavaSerializer. Is this behavior expected? What is an expected configuration for this type of test?

```
    class SomeSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(
      ConfigFactory.parseString("""
    akka.persistence.testkit.events.serialize = off
    akka.actor.allow-java-serialization = on
    """).withFallback(PersistenceTestKitPlugin.config){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the config a bit by using:

```scala
    class SomeSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(
      ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.actor.allow-java-serialization = on")
        .withFallback(EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.config){
```

That `Config` is internally passed to `ActorTestKit`'s constructor so any configuration you need you should add here. I use this to set `Jackson` serializer in my test.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to increase the timeout for the testkit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133027/how-to-increase-default-timeout-for-scalatestwithactortestkit