# How to increase default timeout for ScalaTestWithActorTestKit

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have a test which constructs another event sourcing actor from inside message handler and this construction is taking more than 3 seconds. Below is current configuration, how can I increase default timeout?

```
  extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(
    ConfigFactory.parseString("""
    akka.persistence.testkit.events.serialize = off
    akka.actor.allow-java-serialization = on
    akka.test.single-expect-default = 999s
    """).withFallback(PersistenceTestKitPlugin.config).withFallback(ManualTime.config)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Timeout (3 seconds) during receiveMessage while waiting for message.
java.lang.AssertionError: Timeout (3 seconds) during receiveMessage while waiting for message.
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem here is the timeout? Normally it means that you just don't get response. It would be easier to understand if you shared the internal actor creating code and the interaction code that is timing out

Answer (score 0):

Try with the constructor: *public ScalaTestWithActorTestKit​(com.typesafe.config.Config config)*

similar constructor in (it works for me):

```
extends TestKit(ActorSystem("AliveActorSpec", ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseString("""
                                                                                                                  | akka {
                                                                                                                  |   test {
                                                                                                                  |     single-expect-default = 6s
                                                                                                                  |   }
                                                                                                                  | }
  """.stripMargin))))
```